# The table displays data in one column into the data row in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

someone please help me, I use the CodeIgniter with mvp procedure. I have a database like this:

[image]

is it possible if I want to display data in a table view like this?

[image]

I can only show you on a date, when retrieving data at another date id_status everything is not working.

controller when one date only.

```
public function status()
{
    $tanggal1 = '2017-03-28';
    $data['status'] = $this->M_Reports->status($tanggal1);
    $this->load->view('homepage/template');
    $this->load->view('report/status', $data);
}
```

model :

```
public function status($tanggal1) {
        $sql = "SELECT operasional.id_ops, operasional.id_status, operasional.tanggal, peralatan.nm_peralatan FROM operasional INNER JOIN peralatan ON operasional.id_peralatan = peralatan.id_peralatan WHERE tanggal='$tanggal1' ORDER BY id_ops";
        return $this->db->query($sql)->result();
}
```

And view :

```
<?php
  $start = 0;
  foreach($status as $data) {
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo ++$start ?> </td>
    <td><?php echo $data->nm_peralatan ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data->id_status ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $data->tanggal ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php
  }
?>
```

Comment: why not, your view is based on what you get from your database. You just need to create a query to get the required indexes from your db tables.

Comment: are dates in your view static or dynamic?

Comment: @georoot I was confused when I have to loop id_status when different dates. help me

Comment: @MalikMudassar i hope the dates will be dynamic, i will use between in query

Comment: too long to compose the answer, let me try

Comment: thanks @MalikMudassar

Answer (score 0):

You model function should be like this

```
public function status($top_of_date)
{
    // This will get all dates
    $dates=$this->db->distinct()->select('tanggal')->from('operasional')->get()->result_array();
    // This will get all patients / peralatan
    $patients=$this->db->distinct()->select('id_peralatan')->from('operasional')->get()->result_array();
    // Loop through peralatan
    for($i=0;$i<count($patients);$i++)
    {
        $st=$this->select('id_peralatan')->from('operasional')->WHERE('id_peralatan',$patients[$i])->get()->result_array();
        // Start Creating an array for this index
        $data[$i]=array(
            'id_peralatan'=>$st[0]
        );
        // loop through dates
        for($j=0;$j<count($dates);$j++)
        {
            //if date is greater than top of date
            if($dates[$i]>$top_of_date)
            {
                $st=$this->db->select('id_status')->from('operasional')->WHERE('tanggal',$dates[$i])->get()->result_array();
                // Create index and save the status
                $data[$i]['top_of_date']=$st[0]['id_status'];
            }
            elseif($dates[$i]<$top_of_date)
            {
                $st=$this->db->select('id_status')->from('operasional')->WHERE('tanggal',$dates[$i])->get()->result_array();
                // Create index and save the status
                $data[$i][$dates[$i]]=$st[0]['id_status'];
            }
        }
    }
    return $data;
}
```

Now from your controller you only have to send top of date. like;

```
public function status()
{
   $tanggal_top = '2017-03-28';
   $data['status'] = $this->M_Reports->status($tanggal_top);
   $this->load->view('homepage/template');
   $this->load->view('report/status', $data);
}
```

Comment: Thanks mr. @Malik, i will try this ;)

Comment: Dear mr. @Malik Mudassar , I had an error on line $st=$this->db->select('id_peralatan')->from('operasional')->WHERE('id_peralatan',$patients[$i])->get()->result_array(); because  $patiensts still array, so error like this SELECT `id_peralatan` FROM `operasional` WHERE `id_peralatan` = `Array`

Comment: if you need a prolonged discussion. please join chat http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php with me

Comment: sorry mr. @malik i can't write coment in chat because  i don't have 20 reputation